# How would I check for and manipulate matching value within all rows and columns of 2d list?

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list with random values [[#$%$],[$#$%],[#@$$],[#$%@]]
This is displayed to user as:

```
# $ % $
$ # $ %
# @ $ $
# $ % @
```

The user enters a row number (0-3) and a column number (0-3). How would I check how many consecutive matching characters there are from that point. Matches can be vertical or horizontal from the selected point. must have 2 of the same character in a row to be considered a match.

For example if the user enters row 2 column 2 it would "pick" the bracketed value (it doesn't actually show this part):

```
# $ % $
$ # $ %
# @($)$
# $ % @
```

and then look for matching symbols horizontally or vertically from it.
In this case it should make score =2 because there is 1 dollar sign above and 1 dollar sign to the right of the user point. After matching the 3 symbols, those symbols should be changed from '$' to 'x'
Please help.
This is what I have so far

```
 #checking matches right
    count=0
    for i in range(col, len(board)):
        if(board[row][i] == board[row][col]):
            count+=1
#checking matches left
    for i in range(col, -1, -1):
        if(board[row][i] == board[row][col]):
            count+=1
#checking matches up
    for i in range(row, -1, -1):
        if board[i][col] == board[row][col]:
            count+=1
#checking matches down
    for i in range(row, len(board)):
        if(board[i][col] == board[row][col]):
            count+= 1

    return count
```

Comment: Please show your code attempt.

Comment: I added my attempt so far

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch every symbol horizontally or vertically, you can do it like so.

```
a = ["#$%$", "$#$%", "#@$$", "#$%@"]

print(a[2][2] + "\n")

# Horizontally
for i in range(4):
    print(a[2][i])

print()

# Vertically
for i in range(4):
    print(a[i][2])
```

I'll leave counting the number of matches and modifying them up to you, unless you can show us your code so you can prove you've attempted solving it and so we can help you more specifically.

Comment: i added my attempt so far

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import numpy as np
     
lenght = np.array([[3,5,4,4,9],
               [5,1,3,6,2],
               [3,1,3,3,2],
               [3,1,3,3,2],
               [3,1,3,3,2],
               [3,1,2,5,1]])
print(lenght)
in_row = 2
in_col = 2
in_repl = 99
target_value = lenght[in_row, in_col]
print(target_value)
lenght[np.nonzero(lenght[:, in_col] == target_value), in_col] = 99
lenght[in_row, np.nonzero(lenght[in_row, :] == target_value)] = 99
print(lenght)
```

Output:

```
[[3 5 4 4 9]
 [5 1 3 6 2]
 [3 1 3 3 2]
 [3 1 3 3 2]
 [3 1 3 3 2]
 [3 1 2 5 1]]
3
[[ 3  5  4  4  9]
 [ 5  1 99  6  2]
 [99  1 99 99  2]
 [ 3  1 99  3  2]
 [ 3  1 99  3  2]
 [ 3  1  2  5  1]]
```

Comment: Is there any way you could show me how to do this without using numpy? It would be greatly appreciated.